# How to calculate LAG difference in R - if periods changes or how to add empty NA rows to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

If i have the following dataframe:

```
tibble(
  period = c("2010END", "2011END", 
             "2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END",
             "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END",
             "2011END","2012END"),
  website = c(
    "google",
    "google",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "youtube",
    "youtube"
  ),
  values = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30)
)
```

And would like to find the lag of the values so that i produce the following dataframe:

```
tibble(
  period = c("2010END", "2011END", 
             "2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END",
             "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END",
             "2011END","2012END"),
  website = c(
    "google",
    "google",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "youtube",
    "youtube"
  ),
  values = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30), 
  output = c(NA, 1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 5,5,5,5,5, NA, 10)
)
```

The periods are different - in that one period to lag by is clearly 5 - those going Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,END  and then a secondary lag is by period 2 - those going year_priorEND vs year_aheadEND and maybe even further.

Alternatively:

Instead would it be easier to just impute rows for these missing dates - for example making a condition that says, if there is no website which has a period of 5 (meaning that 5 values exist Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,END) then generate the remainder of the rows for that website and period but have the values as NA, so something like this can be generated instead:

```
tibble(
  period = c("2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END", "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END", 
             "2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END", "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END",
             "2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END", "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END"),
  website = c(
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "google",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "facebook",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube",
    "youtube"
  ),
  values = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1, NA,NA,NA,NA,2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA,NA,NA,NA,20, NA,NA,NA,NA,30), 
  output = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 5,5,5,5,5, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 10)
)
```

So without explicitly coding out which fields need to imputed - i assume some form of checking can occur per group?
Because in this case we can just use `output = lag(values, 5)` as the periods are all consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants a calculate the *year-on-year differences* of the values of a period and the same period in the prior year for each website. There is a related question [Calculating Lag for dataframe in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72189827/3817004) where the OP explicitely asks to calculate *2011Q1 - 2010Q1 and so on including 2011END - 2010END*.

Using `lag()` will only work if the time sequences are complete and the number of positions to lag is always constant. This is not the case for the given dataset.

Therefore, I suggest to use an *update self-join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(inp)[, c("year", "qtr") := tstrsplit(period, "(?<=^\\d{4})", perl = TRUE, 
                                           type.convert = TRUE)][
                                             , prior_year := year - 1L]
inp[inp, on = .(prior_year = year, qtr, website), output := x.values - i.values][]
```

> ```
>      period  website values year qtr prior_year output
>  1: 2010END   google      1 2010 END       2009     NA
>  2: 2011END   google      2 2011 END       2010      1
>  3:  2010Q1 facebook      1 2010  Q1       2009     NA
>  4:  2010Q2 facebook      2 2010  Q2       2009     NA
>  5:  2010Q3 facebook      3 2010  Q3       2009     NA
>  6:  2010Q4 facebook      4 2010  Q4       2009     NA
>  7: 2010END facebook      5 2010 END       2009     NA
>  8:  2011Q1 facebook      6 2011  Q1       2010      5
>  9:  2011Q2 facebook      7 2011  Q2       2010      5
> 10:  2011Q3 facebook      8 2011  Q3       2010      5
> 11:  2011Q4 facebook      9 2011  Q4       2010      5
> 12: 2011END facebook     10 2011 END       2010      5
> 13: 2011END  youtube     20 2011 END       2010     NA
> 14: 2012END  youtube     30 2012 END       2011     10
> ```

#### Explanation

1. `period` is split in two parts, `year` and `qtr`, `year` is coerced to type `integer`. The *regular expression* which is used for splitting uses a *positive lookbehind zero-length assertion* to split the strings right after the first four digits.
2. `prior_year` is computed adn appended to the dataset.
3. In the *update self-join*, for the same `website` and `qtr` `year` is matched with `prior_year`. The difference in value is calcaluated and appended as new column `output`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the output for youtube should be 20? If so, this is a possible solution, however janky:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble( period = c("2010END", "2011END", 
             "2010Q1","2010Q2","2010Q3","2010Q4","2010END",
             "2011Q1","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2011END",
             "2011END","2012END"),
             website = c( "google", "google", "facebook",
                          "facebook", "facebook", "facebook",
                          "facebook", "facebook", "facebook",
                          "facebook", "facebook", "facebook",
                          "youtube", "youtube" ),
             values = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30) )

df %>% 
  extract(period, into = c("Year", "Period"), regex = "([0-9]*)(.*)") %>% 
  group_by(website) %>% 
  mutate(group_rank = match(Year, unique(Year)),
         intstep = if_else(lag(Period) == "END" & group_rank == 2, lag(values), 0)) %>% 
  group_by(website, group_rank) %>% 
  mutate(outcome = if_else(group_rank == 2, first(intstep), as.double(NA))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(group_rank,intstep))
#> # A tibble: 14 × 5
#>    Year  Period website  values outcome
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2010  END    google        1      NA
#>  2 2011  END    google        2       1
#>  3 2010  Q1     facebook      1      NA
#>  4 2010  Q2     facebook      2      NA
#>  5 2010  Q3     facebook      3      NA
#>  6 2010  Q4     facebook      4      NA
#>  7 2010  END    facebook      5      NA
#>  8 2011  Q1     facebook      6       5
#>  9 2011  Q2     facebook      7       5
#> 10 2011  Q3     facebook      8       5
#> 11 2011  Q4     facebook      9       5
#> 12 2011  END    facebook     10       5
#> 13 2011  END    youtube      20      NA
#> 14 2012  END    youtube      30      20
```

The pipeline for this can probably be a lot neater and simpler, I am open to suggestions.